# gradle returns error wen i use android-donations-lib

Tags: android, in-app-billing, donations

Im trying to add the lib Donations from [android-donations-lib](https://github.com/sufficientlysecure/android-donations-lib)

and my app's gradle looks like this:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
//    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.listoapp.listo"
        minSdkVersion 14
    //        minSdkVersion 18
    //        targetSdkVersion 18
            targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
         release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
            'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        google {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "DONATIONS_GOOGLE", "true"
        }
        fdroid {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "DONATIONS_GOOGLE", "true"
        }
    }
}

repositories { mavenCentral() }
dependencies {
    //    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile fileTree(include: 'Parse-*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.3.0'
    //with menus --Doron
    compile 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.7.2.0'
    //Dialogs --Doron
    compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.1.0'
    //for new design
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
    //for add participant

    compile 'com.github.medyo:fancybuttons:1.2@aar' //for fb login button
    compile project(':facebook')
    compile files('libs/ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.9.0.jar')
    compile 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.0.0'
    compile project(':libraries:Donations')
}
```

However, every time i try to run the app it gives me the error:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexFdroidDebug'.

```
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Does anyone have a clue on what this error is?

UPDATE:
I found the problam...i had to temove all traces of my previous billing system...thanks anyway :)

Comment: is it also happening with buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"